# Javascript Dice Roll Multiple Numbers

Tags: javascript, dice

I  am trying to create a diceroll, one that indicates multiple numbers before he settles to one. I tried in a very easy way, but it did not work: Here is my code:

```
<script>


//preload the six images first
var face0=new Image()
face0.src="http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/dices/d1.gif"
var face1=new Image()
face1.src="http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/dices/d2.gif"
var face2=new Image()
face2.src="http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/dices/d3.gif"
var face3=new Image()
face3.src="http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/dices/d4.gif"
var face4=new Image()
face4.src="http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/dices/d5.gif"
var face5=new Image()
face5.src="http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/dices/d6.gif"

function delay(time) {
  var d1 = new Date();
  var d2 = new Date();
  while (d2.valueOf() < d1.valueOf() + time) {
    d2 = new Date();
  }
}
</script>


<img src="http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/dices/d1.gif" name="mydice">
<form><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Throw dice!" onClick="throwdice(); throwdices();">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function DoAllThese() {
throwdice(); 
throwdices();
}

function throwdice(){
delay(500); 
document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face"+5+".src"); 
delay(500); 
throwdices(); 
}

function throwdices(){
var randomdices=Math.round(Math.random()*4.5); 
delay(1000); 
document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face"+randomdices+".src"); 
}
</script>
```

I am not sure how to sequence the numbers so that it looks like as the dice would spin before coming to the solution.

Comment: P.S. Don't name your variables `face0`-`face5`.  This is a bad idea!  Use an array.  `var faces = [];  faces.push(face0);`.  This will let you do `faces[randomdices].src`.  No more `eval()`! :-)

Comment: You also don't need all those images, just make an array of URLs and assign those to `.src` when you want to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval`:

```
function throwdices() {
    var spins = 10;
    var curSpin = 0;
    var spinInterval = setInterval(function() {
        curSpin++;
        if (curSpin < spins) {
            var randomdices=Math.round(Math.random()*4.5);
            document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face"+randomdices+".src");
        } else {
            clearInterval(spinInterval);
            throwdice();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to determine the n'th roll? Like: only the fifth roll is a 6? (I need the code for a scientific experiment and wanted to keep the number of rolls the same. With 6, participants pass this hurdle.

Comment: Create a global `counter` variable, and increment it in `throwdice()`.

Comment: Is your use of `eval` there just trolling?

Comment: I'm just copying the OP's code. I already upvoted the comment that recommended changing to an array. I didn't feel like making all those changes in my answer, to keep it specific to the question that was asked.

Comment: it works great, just another small question (without changing the initial solution: How can I build in an alert (e.g, alert("Great, you passed this stage") ) without it popping up all the time? I inserted it in the else-expression, but it keeps popping up then... ?

Comment: You need to check the value of `randomdices` to see if it's `6`.